# SharePoint Workflow Only Works For Me?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

Ok, I have a workflow built in SharePoint 2010, built in SharePoint Designer. It is set up to begin whenever a new item is created. The library is also set up to create new items based on email attachments. So the goal is for users to email the attachments to the library and the workflow takes over.

The workflow only works for me. The other people attempting to use it are listed as Full Control in the permissions. They are using the correct email address, and the library is creating the new items based on the attachments. The problem is that the workflow keeps saying error occurred.

The error says something about some columns needing different types of data, but when I email to the library it goes off without a hitch.

I am completely stumped as to what could be different about them sending the email instead of me.

Sorry I got kind of long winded, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system account is not allowed to initiate workflow on its own. There is a powershell that you need to run to enable system account to run workflow. Also try impersonation in workflow.

Here found it. 
stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

Comment: But the system account runs the same workflow in a different library, and runs the workflow when I email the documents.  In both of those cases it works exactly as designed, without any type of manual start/approval.

Comment: It works for you be because you are workflow author. Put that workflow under impersonation. Then it should work.

Comment: Redid it and it worked then broke again, then saw this comment about the impersonation. That seems to be the fix, you're my hero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong with it, but I just deleted it then rebuilt it and now it works. Don't think I did anything different so I'm not sure.